# How to read a whole binary file (Nippy) into byte array in Clojure?

Tags: file, serialization, clojure, binary, arrays

I need to convert Nippy data structures stored on disk into something that can be read by Nippy? Nippy uses byte arrays, so I need some way to convert the file into a byte array. I have tried

```
(clojure.java.io/to-byte-array (clojure.java.io/file folder-path file-path))
```

but this gives

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for byte: ?
```

Then I try:

```
(into-array Byte/TYPE  (map byte (slurp (clojure.java.io/file folder-path file-path))))
```

but somehow the namespace is wrong, and I can't find the right one.

To write the Nippy structures in the first place, I am using:

```
(with-open [w (clojure.java.io/output-stream file-path)]
    (.write w (nippy/freeze data)))))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything built-in to Clojure that will handle this. You definitely don't want `slurp` because that will decode the stream contents as text.

You could write your own method to do this, basically reading from the `InputStream` into a buffer and writing the buffer to a `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`. Or you could use the [`IOUtils` class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from Apache Commons IO:

```
 (require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
 (import '[org.apache.commons.io IOUtils])

 (IOUtils/toByteArray (io/input-stream file-path))
```

You should also take a look at Nippy's `thaw-from-in!` and `freeze-to-out!` functions:

```
 (import '[java.io DataInputStream DataOutputStream])

 (with-open [w (io/output-stream file-path)]
   (nippy/freeze-to-out! (DataOutputStream. w) some-data))

 (with-open [r (io/input-stream file-path)]
   (nippy/thaw-from-in! (DataInputStream. r)))
```

Answer (score 33):

Here's how I do it generically with clojure built-ins

```
(defn slurp-bytes
  "Slurp the bytes from a slurpable thing"
  [x]
  (with-open [in (clojure.java.io/input-stream x)
              out (java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.)]
    (clojure.java.io/copy in out)
    (.toByteArray out)))
```

EDIT: Updated answer based on Jerry101's suggestion in comments.

Comment: Thank you so much for writing this answer, it helped me so much in my quest of converting an image to a base64 UTF8 string.

Comment: This is good, but the input-stream should be in a `with-open` binding. You can bind the input and the output in the same `with-open`.

Answer (score 7):

Since you know the `.length` of the file, you can allocate once and use `DataInputStream`'s `readFully` method.  No additional libraries, buffer copies, or loops required.

```lisp
(defn file-to-byte-array
  [^java.io.File file]
  (let [result (byte-array (.length file))]
    (with-open [in (java.io.DataInputStream. (clojure.java.io/input-stream file))]
      (.readFully in result))
    result))
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick make-shift solution may be this code:

```
(defn slurpb [is]
  "Convert an input stream is to byte array"
  (with-open [baos (java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.)]
    (let [ba (byte-array 2000)]
      (loop [n (.read is ba 0 2000)]
        (when (> n 0)
          (.write baos ba 0 n)
          (recur (.read is ba 0 2000))))
      (.toByteArray baos))))

;;test
(String. (slurpb (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream. (.getBytes "hello"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that I just cut Nippy v2.13.0 which now includes a pair of helper utils to help simplify this use case: `freeze-to-file` and `thaw-from-file`.

Release details at: https://github.com/ptaoussanis/nippy/releases/tag/v2.13.0

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to ClojureWerk's Buffy : https://github.com/clojurewerkz/buffy.

Buffy is a Clojure library for working with binary data, writing complete binary protocol implementations in Clojure, storing complex data structures in an off-heap cache, reading binary files and doing everything you would usually do with ByteBuffer.

It's very neat if your binary data is structured as you can define complex composite types and frames depending on structure types, even decode UTF.