# Working with SRTM data in Clojure

Tags: clojure, geospatial, binaryfiles

I have downloaded some of the NASA SRTM elevation data, which comes in binary files. The format is [described as follows](http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/Documentation/SRTM_Topo.pdf):

> The DEM is provided as 16-bit signed integer data in a simple binary
>   raster. There are no header or trailer bytes embedded in the file. The
>   data are stored in row major order (all the data for row 1, followed
>   by all the data for row 2, etc.).
>
> All elevations are in meters referenced to the WGS84/EGM96 geoid as documented at http:// www.NGA.mil/GandG/wgsegm/.
>
> Byte order is Motorola ("big-endian")
>   standard with the most significant byte first. Since they are signed
>   integers elevations can range from -32767 to 32767 meters,
>   encompassing the range of elevation to be found on the Earth.
>
> These
>   data also contain occassional voids from a number of causes such as
>   shadowing, phase unwrapping anomalies, or other radar-specific causes.
>   Voids are flagged with the value -32768.

I am trying to parse these values with clojure for further analysis and visualization. My current code looks like this:

```
;; Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/26372677/2345852
(defn slurp-bytes
  "Slurp the bytes from a slurpable thing"
  [x]
  (with-open [out (java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.)]
    (clojure.java.io/copy (clojure.java.io/input-stream x) out)
    (.toByteArray out)))

(defn read-elevation
  "Reads elevation data stored in .hgt files as provided by the NASA
  SRTM datasets"
  [src]
  (->> (slurp-bytes src)
       (partition 2)
       (map #(reduce + %))))

(read-elevation ...)
```

This however seems to output wrong data: I am looking at the Himalayas and the array holds numbers from -126 to 150. I suggest is because of wrong byte order (executing `(java.nio.ByteOrder/nativeOrder)` returns `LITTLE_ENDIAN`). How do I reverse the byte-order so that it's platform independent?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know much about the elevation data supplied by nasa, but if you want to have a different byte order, simply read through ByteBuffer. If you have a byte array, it could be easily converted to a ByteBuffer by wrapping:

```
(def bb (ByteBuffer/wrap b-array))
(.order bb ByteOrder/BIG_ENDIAN)
```

and to access, you could use any of [ByteBuffer getters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) (i.e. getLong, getDouble, etc).

You could also read the file directly into a ByteBuffer, take a look for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13080619/1027568).